# Как мне разработать статический класс из моего кода

Tags: c#, static

очень нужна помощь, совсем не понимаю((
Функция получает двумерный массив вещественных переменных A. Отыскивает  и  возвращает сумму нечётных значений компонентов массива, лежащих выше главной диагонали.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int n = 5;     // Матрица n * n
            int i, j;      // Счетчики циклов
            int sum = 0;   // Сумма элементов матрицы
            int[,] array = new int[n, n];
 
            // Заполняем матрицу и выводим её на консоль
            Console.WriteLine("Задана матрица:");
            for (i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,3} ", (array[i, j] = random.Next(-5, 10)));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (i < j)
                    {
                        if (array[i, j] % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            sum += array[i, j];
                        }
                    }
                }
              
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\nСумма нечетных элементов матрицы," +
                    $"\nрасположенных выше главной диагонали: {sum}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: Мне нужно разработать статический класс MyClass, и потом протестировать метод этого класса через консоль

Comment: Я не совсем разбираюсь в статических классах функций

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass.SomeFunction()
    }
}


public static class MyClass{
    public static void SomeFunction(){
        //какой-либо код
    }

}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Console.WriteLine оставлять в static class MyClass?

Comment: в SomeFunction вставляешь весь нужный код